# TypeError: role.setPermissions is not a function even though TypeScript says it is

Tags: javascript, discord.js, roles

I was creating a command that loops through all roles in a server, and removes/adds a selected permission (if it can). Hovering over it shows the description of the function.

```js
async execute(client, msg, args, cooldowns, guildForPre, prefix) {
    if(msg.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_ROLES")) {
        let roles = (await msg.guild.roles.fetch()).cache;
        let highPos = getRoleByMention(args[1], msg.guild)?.position || msg.guild.roles.highest.position
        let lowPos = getRoleByMention(args[2], msg.guild)?.position || msg.guild.roles.everyone.position
        roles = roles.filter(r => r.permissions.has(args[0]))
        roles = roles.filter(r => r.position <= highPos && r.position >= lowPos)
        let replaced = ''
        for await (const [, role] of roles) {
            if(role.position >= msg.guild.me.roles.highest.position || role.position >= msg.member.roles.highest.position) continue;
            await role.setPermissions(role.permissions.remove(args[0]))
            (replaced.length) ? replaced += `, ${role.name}` : replaced += `${role.name}`
        }
        msg.channel.send("Replaced roles: " + replaced)
    }
}
```

`getRoleByMention` function:

```js
function getRoleByMention(mention, guild) {
    const id = mention.slice(3, mention.length-1)
    return guild.roles.cache.get(id)
}
```

My command handler arguments are put in correctly, and the command entered is the following:

> m.removeRolePerm MANAGE_MESSAGES @Dyno @Dyno

Is it because they are the same role? The [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Role?scrollTo=setPermissions) say it's a valid function. I am using v12.

Comment: Did you try printing/logging the `role` object to verify that it is what you think it is?

Comment: It showed the role object (Console said `Role {roleinfo}`)

Comment: What about logging `role.setPermissions`?

Comment: shows the function (`[Function: setPermissions]`)

Comment: It sounds like when you're logging it's there, but it's not always there (or not always a function). I'd change that line to `const p = role.setPermissions(/*...*/); await p;` and then set a conditional breakpoint on the first of those, making the condition `typeof role.setPermissions !== "function"`. See if the breakpoint is reached. My guess is it will be, and then you'll know (or be a step closer to knowing) why it's not a function sometimes.

Comment: Well it is always a Role object. When I console logged it I just wrote `console.log(role)` with no `await`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually the statement after. This is because of the lack of semi-colons. Adding a semi-colon should make it work. Changing it to this will remove the error and will make it work too

```js
await role.setPermissions(role.permissions.remove(args[0]))
           if (replaced.length) replaced += `, ${role.name}`
           else replaced += `${role.name}`
```